# JSF Page hangs/freezez in production websphere7 ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, websphere

I have a jsf page constructed using the facelets and icefaces. The page contains a data table and a commandButton , when the command button is pressed a confimation panel is displayed, if we confirm the popup panel, values are populated in the datatable and inserted in the db but after that we are unable to interact with the page. The page freezez. On one production server(WebSphere 7) with ie8 I have this issue, but on on dev server(WebSphere 7) with ie8 i dont have the problem. and i can interact with the page several time. The application is very simple one page for login, home page and then search page. The search page hangs/freezez in production after one interaction but i am unable to produce this on my dev / staging machine. What should i look into.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the application somewhere, e.g. github so it'd be possible to give it a try and eventually fix the issue? Else I don't think there's much information to draw a conclusion from. I would use a Firebug-like environment to see what happens under the covers. It might be that the page keeps waiting for a response.

Comment: I have this configuration on my dev machine. Web sphere 7.0.11 eclipse 3.6.2 and IE8. Everything works fine. On my staging machine i have Web sphere 7.0.21 and ie8 Everything works fine. On one of my production machine i have Web sphere 7.0.13 and ie8 and Everything works fine. and on my other production server i have  Web sphere 7.0.25 and ie8 and page freezes. I replaced the popupPanel with the FacesUtils.addInfoMessage("Message"); and everything works fine, Why my popupPanle is not working on that faulty production envoirnment.I read a lot about the memory leaks due to popupPanel with ie8.